# Perimeter IP Address Blocking

Tags: firewalls, network-access-control

Currently we have a Palo Alto FW that serves as our perimeter devices for our network. We are required by our contract to block certain IP addresses. Over time this list has grown to almost 150k entries. Palo has a limitation on the max number of entries that can be put into an External Dynamic List and we are quickly approaching this limitation. Upgrading hardware isn't an option as that will just kick the can down the road. Are there any other options or appliances that we can use to block IP addresses at the scale we are being requested to block?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Is a DNS sinkhole a solution? What about using a proxy like Squid?

Comment: They are all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, not URLs, so a DNS sinkhole I don't think would work.

Comment: Ok, what about a proxy then?

Comment: If you are lucky then the ips you block are also on a block list feed https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/KCSArticleDetail?id=kA10g000000ClRvCAK. You could also use ipset and iptables.https://github.com/trick77/ipset-blacklist

Comment: @Turdie some of the IP's are duplicate based on a bit of checking. However, its not enough. IP Tables would be nice, but not sure how I can put that in my path between the firewall and our internet circuit.

Comment: You could also look into OPNSense, that's a fully featured firewall open-source Linux image, includes pf which is superior to iptables

Comment: https://www.allthingstech.ch/using-opnsense-and-ip-blocklists-to-block-malicious-traffic